# NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "xxxxx" network: failed to set bridge addr: "cni0" already has an IP address different from10.x.x.x - Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud-foundry, flannel, pivotaltracker

I get this error after I start the worker node VMs(`Kubernetes`) from the `AWS` console. I am using `PKS` ( `Pivotal Container Service`)

> network for pod "xxxxx": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "xxxxx" network: failed to set bridge addr: "cni0" already has an IP address different from 10.x.x.x/xx

I supppose that `Flannel` assigns a subnet lease to the workers in the cluster, which expires after 24 hours - and `flannel.1` and `cni0 /24` subnet no longer match, which causes this issue.

I also know a workaround:

```
bosh ssh -d worker -c "sudo /var/vcap/bosh/bin/monit stop flanneld" 
bosh ssh -d worker -c "sudo rm /var/vcap/store/docker/docker/network/files/local-kv.db" 
bosh ssh -d worker -c "sudo /var/vcap/bosh/bin/monit restart all"
```

However is there any permanent fix to this?

Comment: Hi, it seems like You need to reinitialize the pod network every time the node starts up. Maybe the `--pod-network-cidr` value is incorrect. Are these worker nodes the same versions as master nodes? Can You share k8s versions of nodes and flannel cni version?

Comment: Yup, they are the same version,

Comment: I am using K8s Version 1.15.5,i see the cni0 and flannel have ips that are not from the same subnet
 My pod network cidr is 10.200.0.0/16

 On one of the worker nodes, ifconfig ouptut is like this:

cni0      Link encap:Ethernet  
          inet addr:10.200.28.1  Bcast:10.200.28.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          
flannel.1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          inet addr:10.200.42.0  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255



Subnet.env has this:


`FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.200.0.0/16`
`FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.200.42.1/24`
`FLANNEL_MTU=8951`
`FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true`

Answer (score 26):

### TL;DR - recreate network

```
$ ip link set cni0 down
$ brctl delbr cni0
```

Or, as @ws_ suggested in comments - remove interfaces and restart k8s services:

```
ip link set cni0 down && ip link set flannel.1 down 
ip link delete cni0 && ip link delete flannel.1
systemctl restart containerd && systemctl restart kubelet
```

### Community solutions

It is a [`known issue`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39557)

And there are some solutions to fix it.

Solution by [filipenv](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39557#issuecomment-271944481) is:

> on master and slaves:
>
> ```
> $ kubeadm reset
> $ systemctl stop kubelet
> $ systemctl stop docker
> $ rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
> $ rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/*
> $ rm -rf /etc/cni/
> $ ifconfig cni0 down
> $ ifconfig flannel.1 down
> $ ifconfig docker0 down
> ```
>
> you may need to manually `umount` filesystems from `/var/lib/kubelet` before calling rm on that dir)
> After doing that I started docker and kubelet back again and restarted the kubeadm process

[aysark:](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39557#issuecomment-342604193) and [kubernetes-handbook](https://github.com/feiskyer/kubernetes-handbook/blob/master/en/troubleshooting/pod.md) in a recipe for [`Pod stuck in Waiting or ContainerCreating`](https://github.com/feiskyer/kubernetes-handbook/blob/master/en/troubleshooting/pod.md#pod-stuck-in-waiting-or-containercreating) both recommend

```
$ ip link set cni0 down
$ brctl delbr cni0
```

### Some workarounds from Flannel's KB article

And there is an article in `Flannel`'s KB: [PKS Flannel network gets out of sync with docker bridge network (cni0)](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/PKS-Flannel-network-gets-out-of-sync-with-docker-bridge-network-cni0)

#### Workaround 1:

WA1 is just like yours:

```
    bosh ssh -d <deployment_name> worker -c "sudo /var/vcap/bosh/bin/monit stop flanneld"
    bosh ssh -d <deployment_name> worker -c "sudo rm /var/vcap/store/docker/docker/network/files/local-kv.db"
    bosh ssh -d <deployment_name> worker -c "sudo /var/vcap/bosh/bin/monit restart all"
```

#### Workaround 2:

If WA1 didn't help, KB recommends:

```
    bosh ssh -d <deployment_name> worker -c "sudo /var/vcap/bosh/bin/monit stop flanneld"
    bosh ssh -d <> worker -c "ifconfig | grep -A 1 flannel"
    On a master node get access to etcd using the following KB 
    On a master node run `etcdctlv2 ls /coreos.com/network/subnets/`
    Remove all the worker subnet leases from etcd by running `etcdctlv2 rm /coreos.com/network/subnets/<worker_subnet>;` for each of the worker subnets from point 2 above.
    bosh ssh -d <deployment_name> worker -c "sudo /var/vcap/bosh/bin/monit restart flanneld"
```

Comment: this works for me (k8s 1.21 with containerd): 1. `ip link set cni0 down && ip link set flannel.1 down`  2. `ip link delete cni0 && ip link delete flannel.1`   3. `systemctl restart containerd && systemctl restart kubelet`

Comment: Your comment worked for me as well. Thanks @ws_

Comment: You saved me dude. This is working perfectly in 1.23.x

Comment: It work also for me but i have to remove flannels pod running on this node

Answer (score 2):

I am running docker with kubernetes. Did the following on all my master and slave nodes and got my cluster work:

```
sudo su
ip link set cni0 down && ip link set flannel.1 down 
ip link delete cni0 && ip link delete flannel.1
systemctl restart docker && systemctl restart kubelet
```